# android :geo Location using intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclick, parse-server

I have a ListView and when i click a single item it goes to single item view . in each single item view page there is a location button  .I need to go to google map when click the location button

*longtitute and latitudes are saved in database like this . 
I want to call this dynamically
in EACH CELL OF THE COLUMN ,  data is stored like this,*

---

**the data is stored as object inside parse database, not as strings**

> {"lat":25.1250241,"lng":55.3752069}

anyone knows please tell how can i get data from this?

```
           btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5) ;
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56) ;
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    String data = String.format("geo:%s,%s", latitude, longitude);

                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(data));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: means you need to get Data from  "{"lat":25.1250241,"lng":55.3752069}" this String.

Comment: yes , this is the data inside one cell  @Chetan

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**finally  found way ..**

> this is the code i use to get only the coordinates

```
   showCorporate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.individualEmail);
        showCorporate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] location = corporateLocation.split(",");
                double lat, lng;
                try{
                    lat = fetchDouble(location[0], true);
                    lng = fetchDouble(location[1], false);
                    Log.d("Co-Ordinates",""+lat+", "+lng);
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    String data = String.format("geo:%s,%s", lat, lng);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(data));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }catch (NullPointerException npe){
                    Toast.makeText(SingleCorporate.this, "Sorry No Location Available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Below method to parse your data from String you need pass one paramaeter in below method when I passes string.

```
private void parseJsonData(){
        try {
            String jsonString = "{\"lat\":25.1250241,\"lng\":55.3752069}";
            Object object = new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
            if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.optString("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.optString("lat"));

                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"lat="+lat);
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"lng="+lng);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: hi   thanks you, but this is not static data,  the data structure is like above but the data is dynamic from database similar to that phone number  code you answered yesterday  ..  @Chetan

Comment: yes , You need to pass your string in place of jsonString .

Comment: oh thanks .. can I use this code inside click event @Chetan

Comment: and one more thing , the data is stored as object  inside parse database , not as string  @Chetan

Comment: Yes you can use it in your click event.