# Disable button click : only when field is empty

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

**this Question is different because this is using api data to intent and then if you use normal if else condition its not working . check the right answer below and the condition of it** ----------

hi,
I'm trying to get android call service to a button click ,button is inside a `ListView` when I click one list item it goes to single item view in that single item view each single item has a mobile number attached to call button . Numbers are stored in parse data base and i'm calling using parse api .

Now when I'm clicking a number it goes to call function . what I need is, suppose a single view doesn't have a mobile number , the button should not be clickable.If anyone knows please help me.

> edited answer as one of below anwer but this also not working

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56) ;
                btn.setClickable(false);

                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        String phno = object.getString("telephone");
                        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" +phno));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

Below is my code

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56) ;
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    String phno = object.getString("telephone");
                    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" +phno));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Comment: this is different please check it .  @Rotwang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check and  set your button enable to false , also clickable false, and you can and set above status to button within `getView()` of your Adapter so its pre disable if your mobile number field are empty in your data List

```
mButton.setClickable(false);
mButton.setEnabled(false);
```

put below code before you are adding Click Listener to button.

```
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56) ;
    String phno = object.getString("telephone");

    if(phno==null || phno.equals("")){
        mButton.setClickable(false);
        mButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
else{
        mButton.setEnabled(true);
        mButton.setClickable(true);
}
```

Comment: can you provide get view code also  i didnt understand that part

Comment: if  you have Listview then When you set phone data in your adapter ,So while you are set phone number to button then place one if condition for empty string and if your string is empty then disable your button.

Comment: see my updated answer.@FaizalMohamed

Comment: setEnable is in read  "cannot resolve method"  error

Comment: setEnabled() use this method  name was wrong

Comment: app crashes and Process: app.com.anew.fbcapplication5, PID: 12093
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference error message

Comment: put check for null too.

Comment: see mu updated answer i have added condition for null check for too.

Comment: nul also crashing    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference   this error showing

Comment: i Added your modified answer it is working on button al the time  when there is number also button is not clickable

Comment: Then Add else condition too and enable and clickable  by passing true into button.

Comment: ok  .can you send me code to put inside else please

Comment: I added a blank else condtion  but stil button is disabled all the time

Comment: see my updated code.

Comment: I added it always not editable

Comment: pelase check in else having true set on both methods

Comment: thnaks @Chetan working fine :)

Comment: please check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468580/android-geo-location-using-intent  @Chetan

Answer (score 2):

One way to go at it is using `Button.setClickable`

```
Button button;//initialize, add onClickListener, styling, whatever you need
button.setClickable(true/false);//This is what sets it clickable/unclickable
```

So see if there is a number/value present(if you are using EditText or something else that requires input) and `setClickable` true or false depending on if there is a value or not

And to make sure there is a value, add to the onClickListener:

```
String string = editText.getText();
if(string.equals("")){
    //throw exception, show toast, whatever you feel like doing in the event that the button is pressed in an unclickable state
    return;
}
```

**Example integration**

```
    Button btn;//initialize, set listeners, etc
    btn.setClickable(false);//edittext has no input initially, so set the button as unclickable
    EditText et;//initialize
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            //s is the input in form of a charsequence that has a length for each char. Meaning if it isn't 0, there is input and the button is clickable. If it is 0, there is no text and the button should not be clickable
            if(s.length() != 0)
                btn.setClickable(true);
            else
                btn.setClickable(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi thanks ., can you give full code i mean can tyou impliment in my question please .. I'm novice developer unable to impliment your code in mine

Comment: Adding code now. See update shortly

Comment: hi thnaks where can I impliment click function in this

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site for help with specific problems. Integrating is for you to handle. This site is not a code writing service

Comment: ok sory ..but i dont think i can impliment your code in my code anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you will need to evaluate this before the onClick event.

Setup a boolean and evaluate if the field has data. Then use `btn.setClickable(false);` if the statement comes back as false.

Comment: btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56) ;

                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        btn.setClickable(false);
                        String phno = object.getString("telephone");
                        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" +phno));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

Comment: I added this but still empty is working

Comment: Comments codes are hard to read :P looks like you set the clickable inside the onClick event. Evaluate the setClickable prior to your onClick. Otherwise you're still executing the rest of the code in the onClick event

Comment: i did that also  but not working empty also showing

Comment: Can you edit your initial question with the new code? Hard to tell from comments.

Comment: By empty also showing do you mean it's still clickable or that it is visible?

Comment: if the phone number is empty in database  also button is working ,, I need if the number is empty button should not be clickable or a toast ..

Comment: btn.setEnabled(false); try this instead of Clickable

Comment: Process: app.com.anew.fbcapplication5, PID: 12093
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference  app crashes this error showing

Answer (score 1):

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button56) ;
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String phno = object.getString("telephone");
                    if(! phno.equals(""))
                     {

                       Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" +phno));
                    startActivity(i);
                     }
                      else
                           //generate toast here


                }
            });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i added this code then  app  crashes  :(  is there anything else i need to modify @Shubham Agarwal Bhewanewala

Comment: I have edited the code and make sure that phno is not null

Comment: please check the answer again else is not with brakect and after i aded braks  when there is no number app crashes

Comment: see there i wrote generate Toast there and a single line statment doesnot need bracket. try debugging each line to check which line causes crash. And there is nothing wrong with code. if still not found check stack trace in logcat

Comment: ok i'll try now

Comment: I tried to putt toast but get activity is in red and could not add insdie else .can you help me

Comment: Toast.makeText(getContext(),"some string", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); or Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: cannot resolve method getcontext  error is showing